# Move ownership from std::shared_ptr to std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a class `A` which has a field of type `std::unique_ptr`:

```
class A
{
public:
   std::unique_ptr pointer;
// class body
};
```

And somewhere in code, I'm using few `std::shared_ptr`s which point to the same object. Now what I'd like to achieve is to move ownership to this `std::unique_ptr` in my class, so that if all `shared_ptr`s will be destroyed, my object will stay alive as long as this `unique_ptr` will stay alive.

My question is - is it possible to move ownership from `std::shared_ptr` to `std::unique_ptr` and if yes, how can I do this?

Comment: Logically such a scenario doesn't make sense to me. Suppose for a while that it is possible to transfer the onwership, but you could do that *only when* you're sure that there is only **one** `shared_ptr` alives; if that is the case, then you can still use `shared_ptr` as member of `A` and **pretend** that it is `unique_ptr`.

Comment: "move ownership to this std::unique_ptr in my class, so that if all shared_ptrs will be destroyed, my object will stay alive as long as this unique_ptr will stay alive..." Why not make just one more shared in A?

Comment: what if there are N other shared ptrs pointing to the same object? How could  you possibly handle that? `shared_ptr` doesn't provide `release` method for a reason.

Comment: You could fudge it by checking the reference count and checking it is 1, but you shouldn't. What would you do if it wasn't equal to 1?

Comment: @Nawaz That's true, I could create `shared_ptr` in `A` class. I think I misunderstood a concept a bit again. I wanted to behave it in this way: if `unique_ptr` dies, the object itself dies too, even though `shared_ptr`s still point to it, but that's silly as they wouldn't know that object itself was destroyed and therefore they wouldn't be `nullptr`s. Post it as an answer so that I can accept it. :-)

Comment: Maybe what you want is a shared_ptr in A and all other weak_ptr??

Comment: @Mosquito: In that case, you're looking at the wrong smart pointer. What you probably need is called `std::weak_ptr`. If so, then make sure you use one `std::shared_ptr` and all others as `std::weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Logically such a scenario doesn't make sense to me.

Suppose for a while that it is possible to transfer the ownership, but you could do that *only when* you're sure that there is only **one** `shared_ptr` alives; if that is the case, then you can still use `shared_ptr` as member of `A` and **pretend** that it is `unique_ptr`.

And then you commented:

> That's true, I could create `shared_ptr` in A class. I think I misunderstood a concept a bit again. I wanted to behave it in this way: if `unique_ptr` dies, the object itself dies too, even though `shared_ptr`s still point to it, but that's silly as they wouldn't know that object itself was destroyed and therefore they wouldn't be `nullptr`s.

In that case, you're looking at the wrong smart pointer. What you probably need is called [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). If so, then make sure you use one [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and all others as `std::weak_ptr`.

Comment: Well, in fact the scenario just came up legitimately for me since my code uses `unique_ptr` (for good reasons), but I have to get data from a lib that can't handle noncopyable types. Sure, I'll want to fix the lib, but upstream & deployment will take time, so there you have it.